# Change the contents of a rdp-file with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, replace, str-replace

I have a directory C:\RDP LINKS\ in which you find a whole bunch of folders with rdp shortcuts.

The problem is, is that the default name in all of the shortcuts has been changed recently (first it was administrator@testdomain.local and now it's administrator@test2domain.local.

i want to change the contents of the rdp links with Powershell.

If you open the rdp shortcut with notepad, you can see the properties and the default user name:

[image]

I tried this script:

```
$configFiles = Get-ChildItem "C:\RDP LINKS\" *.rdp -rec
foreach ($file in $configFiles)
{
    (Get-Content $file.PSPath) |
    Foreach-Object { $_ -replace "administrator@testdomain.local", "administrator@test2domain.local" } |
    Set-Content $file.PSPath
}
```

The script runs but the name doesn't change. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Look at the [`WScript.Shell` COM object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aew9yb99(v=vs.84).aspx), and its methods and members. You'll need to pay special attention to the `CreateShortcut()` and `Save()` methods.

Comment: Thanks Jeff, why would the `createShortcut()` be in my interest if the shortcuts are already there

Comment: Its purpose is to create the appropriate data structure _in memory_; if you pass it a path to an extant shortcut file, it will read the data in and create the structure in memory already populated; if the path doesn't pre-exist, it will create a "blank" structure in memory with all of the fields. The `Save()` method will write out the data to the designated file.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin These aren't that kind of shortcut.  These are .rdp files, not .lnk files.  WScript.Shell doesn't know anything about .rdp files.  .rdp files are text files that contain settings that `mstsc.exe` interprets.

Comment: @BaconBits - Whoops! I missed that; got focussed on "shortcuts", and missed "rdp". You're right; WScript.Shell is definitely for .lnks, not .rdps.

Comment: @BaconBits ,Thanks, but shouldn't my code be working if .rdp files are interpret as text files?

Comment: You have a space after your username `"administrator@testdomain.local "` I assume that you replace is not doing anything because of it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this instead (use fullname property instead of pspath) :

```
 ls "c:\rdp links\*.rdp" -recurse | %{
     (gc $_ ) -replace "administrator@testdomain.local", "administrator@test2domain.local" |
     set-content $_.FullName -force
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this didn't work though (script runs but no changes)

Comment: Rdp files are not shortcuts

Comment: @LoïcMICHEL - Yeah, had my attention drawn to that above; got hung up on 'shortcut' and missed 'rdp'. If you edit the answer a trifle, I'll retract the downvote.

Comment: Try to run each Line interactively tout figure where it fails. Works fine on my station...

Answer (score 1):

You were over thinking it. this is a straight up -replace.

```
$configFiles = (Get-ChildItem "C:\RDP LINKS\" *.rdp) 
foreach ($file in $configFiles)
    {
    (get-content $file) -replace 'administrator@testdomain.local', 'administrator@test2domain.local' | set-content $file
}
```