# Edit RDP File C#

Tags: c#, edit, rdp, custom-application

I want to run an RDP file,
But before running I want to edit one of its parameters using C# code.
I can do this manually by right-clicking RDP.rdp-> opening using a text document etc.
Is it possible that this will be done automatically using C#?

Comment: No, you will have to do some programming....

Comment: Open file in C#, modify it and save. Just treat it as regular txt file.

Comment: Or try Powershell.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48813786/change-the-contents-of-a-rdp-file-with-powershell

Comment: @kosist Thanks,
Can you send me a sample code of how to do this? I'm new to C #